# Mule - Communication between Web application and Mule ESB

Tags: java, mule

My web application is on following address:

> `http://localhost:8080/MyProject/page-obj.html`

I am calling Mule Project, from a Web Application(deployed on glassfish), having following URL in page:

```
`<form action="http://localhost:28146/CallObject" method="post" id="objform">`
```

Mule project is executing something on remote server and returning Success.

I want to redirect success to another page say

> `http://localhost:8080/MyProject/page-sucess.html`

When redirect, i see `http://localhost:28146/CallObject` on address bar, instead of `http://localhost:8080/MyProject/page-sucess.html`. Secondly, i am unable to load CSS and JS properly. I think i am not handling this properly

Following is Mule Flow in use:

`

```
<http:endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:8080/MyProject/page-sucess.html" name="page" method="POST"/>

    <flow name="Create_Work_Flow" doc:name="Create_Work_Flow">
         <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:28146/CallObject" contentType="text/html" doc:name="Request">
            <http:body-to-parameter-map-transformer doc:name="HTMLForm-Parameters-To-Mule"/>
        </http:inbound-endpoint>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Form-Parameters"  message="#[payload]" />

        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP" ref="Page">
            <custom-transformer class="com.ExecuteWorkflow" doc:name="Call-CreateWorkflow"/>
        </http:outbound-endpoint>

    </flow>`
```

Answer (score 1):

Have your Mule flow set redirect headers in the success case and the browser should follow the redirect:

```
<flow name="Create_Work_Flow" doc:name="Create_Work_Flow">
     <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:28146/CallObject" contentType="text/html" doc:name="Request">
        <http:body-to-parameter-map-transformer doc:name="HTMLForm-Parameters-To-Mule"/>
    </http:inbound-endpoint>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Form-Parameters"  message="#[payload]" />
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP" ref="Page">
        <custom-transformer class="com.ExecuteWorkflow" doc:name="Call-CreateWorkflow"/>
    </http:outbound-endpoint>
    <set-property propertyName="http.status" value="301"/>
    <set-property propertyName="Location" value="http://localhost:8080/MyProject/page-
</flow>
```

Comment: It is throwing error that : property is not allowed to be child element of HTTP.

Comment: I've corrected my example.  You should use the set-property element instead of property.

Comment: It is working without  <http:outbound-endpoint> around Custom Transformer too. I think i should remove that as i could not see any usage of that